# gcc: division by zero

Tags: c, gcc-warning, avr-gcc

I am getting **division by zero** error at this line:

```
if (tim2_st_ovf < T2_PREK_250)
```

These values are defines like this:

```
volatile uint8_t tim2_st_ovf = 0;

#define T2_PREK_250    ((250 * (F_CPU / 1000)) / ((UINT8_MAX + 1) * 1024))
#define F_CPU    16000000UL
```

And `UINT8_MAX` equals to 255.

Why am I getting this? I calculated it several times on calculator and am getting ~15. Also, if I change 1024 to 1023 it doesnt show any error.

Comment: Please post an http://sscce.org/ (including the `main` function).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`((UINT8_MAX + 1) * 1024)` may become 0, because `UINT8_MAX + 1` is usually 256, and `256 * 1024` is 0 modulo 2<sup>16</sup>. So if `sizeof(int) == 2` on your achitecture, then you get 0.

On the typical modern desktop architectures with GCC, `sizeof(int) == 4`, and you wouldn't get the division by 0.

To fix it, replace `1024` with `1024UL`. That will work, because `unsigned long` is guaranteed to go up to 4294967295. (Thanks to Pascal Cuoq for explaining it.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the solution and the explanation! I will accept the anwser as soon as I can.

Comment: I'd say this is backed up by the fact that `16000000` is marked with `UL` in the next line, whereas this would comfortably fit inside a 32-bit integer (this also implies that `ULL` would indeed be overkill on this platform).

Comment: `unsigned long` is guaranteed to go up to `4294967295`, so there is no way that replacing `1024` with `1024UL` can fail to work.